# Trying to create an eye tracking script with clamping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

This works fine, but when I turn the isLookingAtPlayer boolean to false, it does not stop.  I also tried storing the initial value of the rotation of the transform, and it did not work when I reset it.  Any idea how I can set the eye position to the default value when not looking at player?

```cs
    public Transform eyeL;
    public Transform eyeR;
    public Transform player;
    public bool isLookingAtPlayer;
    public float damping;
    public float eyeMinRange = -40.7f;
    public float eyeMaxRange = 35.2f;

    void Update() {
        if(isLookingAtPlayer) {
            EyesLookAtPlayer();
        }
    }
    void EyesLookAtPlayer() {
        eyeL.LookAt(player.position);
        eyeR.LookAt(player.position);
        Vector3 newEyeL = eyeL.rotation.eulerAngles;
        Vector3 newEyeR = eyeR.rotation.eulerAngles;
        newEyeL.y = Mathf.Clamp(newEyeL.y, eyeMinRange, eyeMaxRange);
        newEyeL.x = -90f;
        newEyeL.z = -180f;
        newEyeR.y = Mathf.Clamp(newEyeR.y, eyeMinRange, eyeMaxRange);
        newEyeR.x = -90f;
        newEyeR.z = -180f;
        eyeL.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newEyeL);
        eyeR.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newEyeR);
    }
```

Comment: define "does not stop" - does it still follow? How did you "reset" the `isLookingAtPlayer` ? Because setting `public bool isLookingAtPlayer = false` would not work because Inspector overrides the value. It works in `Start()` or `Update()` of course - but not in initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them and use the default rotation while the condition is false

```
private Quaternion defaultR;
private Quaternion defaultL;

const float rotX = -90f;
const float rotZ = -180f;

private void Start()
{
    defaultR = eyeR.localRotation;
    defaultL = eyeL.localRotation;
}

void Update() 
{
    if(isLookingAtPlayer) 
    {
        EyesLookAtPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        eyeL.localRotation = defaultL;
        eyeR.localRotation = defaultR;
    }
}

void EyesLookAtPlayer() 
{
    eyeL.LookAt(player.position);
    eyeR.LookAt(player.position);

    // Since later you are applying the clamped rotations to the 
    // localRotation I would also here take the localEulerAngles
    var newEyeL = Mathf.Clamp(eyeL.localEulerAngles.y, eyeMinRange, eyeMaxRange);      
    var newEyeR = Mathf.Clamp(eyeR.localEulerAngles.y, eyeMinRange, eyeMaxRange);
    
    eyeL.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, newEyeL, rotZ);
    eyeR.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, newEyeR, rotZ);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I’ll give this a shot!